# How to edit header in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

I'm in Odoo15 and i want to modify the header in Odoo view

I have **Quotations / S00156** like in the image, but the client want only the first 3 numbers, should look something like this **Quotations / S156**

How can I modify this in Odoo? I only have to modify the way it looks like in this view. Thanks! :)

[image]

Comment: You have to either change the sequence used for sales order or if you only want to change the displayed name of sales orders you have to override the related compute method, usually `_compute_display_name`.

Answer (score 0):

if you use custom module then you are go to the folder in custom module **view/view.xml** add the file in

```
<menuitem id="sample_id" name="DISPLAY_NAME"
                  parent="SALES.SALES" sequence="20"
                  groups="SALES.GROUP_SALES" action="SALES"/>
```

I write caps_leter words change your sales page configuration.
you are find the page configuration activate the debug button(find up on the page click debug symbol) then click **open view** find all configuration details

Answer (score 0):

It is not needed to edit odoo breadcrumbs to achieve this.
The name generated from `sale.order` model is a sequence handled by `ir.sequence` model.

You can customize it via Settings -> Technical Functions -> Sequences.

Find the ir.sequence record having `sale.order` as Sequence Key.

Edit Sequence size from 5 to 3.

If you can't see "Technical Functions" menu item from Settings page, you need to enable debug mode.

You can activate debug mode via Settings -> Development Tools -> Enable Debug Mode. This section is only available for Admin users.

In case editing `ir.sequence` record is not enough, you'll need to manually inherit `sale.order` module as CZoellner said and override `name_get` function.

```
class SaleOrder(models.Model):
  _inherit = "sale.order"
  
  def name_get(self):
    res = super(SaleOrder, self).name_get()
    // Your Logic here
    return res
```